# Self study text for Elementary Number theory

Tags: elementary-number-theory

What is a very helpful book for elementary number theory? I would like to teach myself and I need help finding a book that would be able to do this.

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: I learned from this one and I really liked it, you can get it on amazon for a penny plus shipping: https://smile.amazon.com/Introduction-Number-Theory-William-Adams/dp/0134912829/ref=sr_1_2?s=instant-video&ie=UTF8&qid=1470148190&sr=8-2&keywords=number+theory+adams

Comment: @Gregory Grant- Thank You.

Answer (score 1):

[George Andrew's number theory](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0486682528) is fun and good.

[Ivan Niven's book](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0471625469) is complete and covers continuous fractions really well

[Ireland and Rosen's modern number theory](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0471625469) is a master piece, but requires some notions of modern algebra

Answer (score 1):

There are several elementary number theory books available from Dover. Since they are really inexpensive you can get several and see the same material expressed in several ways, which may help you in self study.

http://store.doverpublications.com/by-subject-mathematics-theory.html

Friedbergs's "An Adventurers Guide to Number Theory" is off-beat but perhaps interesting. Also Dover, her's the Amazon link:
[https://www.amazon.com/Adventurers-Guide-Number-Theory-Mathematics/dp/0486281337](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0486281337)